# How to get information from an array iteration that uses {{this}} and delete item Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

Hi guys I have tried this approach to get information from an array of Meteor.users but it's not working and I don't have any idea to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Publish users

```
Deps.autorun(function (handle) {

Meteor.publish('directory', function () {
  if (this.userId) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  var x = user.profile.x;
  return Meteor.users.find({"profile.x": x});
  } else {
    handle.stop();
  }
});
});

Meteor.users.allow({

  remove:function() {
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var x = user.profile.x;
    if(x === "admin") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    },
});
```

Helper:

```
listTeam: function () {
    var userTeam = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
    return _.map(userTeam || [], function(user) { return user.emails[0].address || user._id;});
 },
```

Template:

```
<ul>
{{#each listTeam}}
<div>
<li id="item">{{this}}</li><button id="deleteTeam" class="button">Delete</button>
</div>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

First approach:

```
'click #deleteTeam': function (event, template) {
    var id = template.data._id;
    Meteor.users.remove({_id:id});

  }
```

Returns undefined (only in the first item of iteration)

I've tried with jQuery but it's not useful since I just get the email address and the first item only.(I'm not iterating id's and I think this seems not to be a good solution).

Comment: Separate your code into client and server blocks.  You have nested publish, which is server only, inside of Deps.autorun which is client only.

Answer (score 0):

Inside template event functions you can use this to get the instance data.
Example:

```
'click #deleteTeam': function (event, template) {
    var id = this._id;
    Meteor.users.remove({_id:id});
}
```

or alternatively shorter:

```
'click #deleteTeam': function () {
    Meteor.users.remove({_id: this._id});
}
```

if you run into further issues, it might be a permissions problem, I recommend using this pattern:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  remove: function(userId, doc) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
    return user ? user.profile.admin : false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Pent thanks for your prompt answer. But when I use the var id=this._id; it returns undefined. And only for the first item. Maybe because I'm using _.map?

Comment: I notice you're using underscore to map, Meteor has it's own map built into the cursor. You can try using that.